# React-Native dependencies integration issue

Tags: react-native

I'm beginner in react-native Sorry in advance  if found issues in question asking.
I cloned a repository from remote server where now i've empty node_modules directory. I've "package.json" file with all dependencies list while when I run "npm install" I didn't get dependencies in node_modules directory and got number of warnings on terminal related to different files as you can see here[image].

Comment: had you try `yarn install` ?

Comment: close your terminal and google chrome debugger if it is open and then remove node-modules folders and then try the npm install again

Comment: @anztrax Yes i tried, but I think repository project is based on old " NPM" version when i removed all dependencies from "package. JSON" and install one by one then i got all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

delete node_modules folder.
Then try to do `npm install` first. it ll added node modules folder.

after that try to install dependancies..you can find necessary dependancies from json file.

ex:- `npm install --save depencencyname@versionnumber`

for some modules you have to link them before it use..
using `react-native link dependancyname`